# Python Mysql select query error message: Failed to get record from MySQL table: Python type list cannot be converted

Tags: python, mysql

I newbie using Python with Mysql. I created the following Python script with mysql Select query. However, it doesn't work properly.

...

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
#empty list
userid_in_the_table=[]
questionid_in_the_table=[]
questionid_in_the_table1=[]


#######Mysql database connection################
try:
    mySQLConnection=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
    database='itemstatistics',
    user='adminUser',
    password='passwordAdmin')
    cursor=mySQLConnection.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor=mySQLConnection.cursor(prepared=True)

 #######quiz_grade_table###########

    sql_select_query= """select userid from mdl_quiz_grades where quiz=2"""
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in record:
        userid_in_the_table.append(row)
        print(row)
    print("List values")
    print(userid_in_the_table)
    userid_list=[list(ele1) for ele1 in userid_in_the_table]

############ letteranswers table ###################
    sql_select_query1="""select distinct questionid from letteranswers"""
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query1)
    record1=cursor.fetchall()
    for row1 in record1:
        questionid_in_the_table.append(row1)

    questionid_list=[list(ele) for ele in questionid_in_the_table]

    for userid in userid_list:
        for questionid in questionid_list:
            sql_select_query2="""Select usersquestionanswerid.userid,
            usersquestionanswerid.questionid,
            letteranswers.letter
            from
            usersquestionanswerid, letteranswers
            where userid=%s
            and usersquestionanswerid.questionid=%s
            and usersquestionanswerid.answerids=letteranswers.answersid
            and usersquestionanswerid.questionid=letteranswers.questionid"""
            cursor.execute(sql_select_query2, (userid, questionid))
            record=cursor.fetchall()
            for row2 in record:
                questionid_in_the_table1.append(row2)

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

finally:
    if (mySQLConnection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        mySQLConnection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
        print( "Userid")
        print(userid_in_the_table)
        total= len(userid_in_the_table)
        print ("Total Users id")
        print (total)
        total1=len(questionid_in_the_table)
        print ("Total questions")
        print (total1)
        print(questionid_in_the_table)
        print(type(questionid_in_the_table))
        print(questionid_in_the_table)
        print(userid_in_the_table)
        print(questionid_in_the_table1)
```

...

However, the computer screen sent back the following message:
Failed to get record from MySQL table: Python type list cannot be converted

What I did wrong ?

Any comments are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the exactly error message? Including the lines? Thanks

Comment: Python error: Failed to get record from SQL table: Python type list cannot be converted.

Comment: I tested here and it worked with fake tables. On the capture block `except mysql.connector.Error as error:` add an  `raise error` after the `print` and post the message.

Comment: raise error
  File "accumulativeanswers1.py", line 52, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query2, (userid, questionid))
  File "/home/mbriseno/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 944, in execute
    res = self._cnx.cmd_stmt_execute(self._stmt, *params)
  File "/home/mbriseno/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 455, in cmd_stmt_execute
    raise errors.InterfaceError(str(err))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted